# Convert a NetBeans build.xml for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ant

I would like to know if there is a way to convert the file build.xml ant created for Netbeans with a build.xml file that can run on eclipse

thanks to all

Comment: Is the build.xml specific for netbeans? If its just Ant then it should already work. Eclipse contains Ant. Perhaps post the xml file or the parts of it that gives you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any tool to do this. You may need to convert by hand.

Let's check the netbeans project structure.

Netbeans generates a `build.xml` for the project (at the root folder of the project), however, this build file doesn't contain any targets. All the generated targets are placed in `nbproject/build-impl.xml`. By doing this, the generated content and the content that may be added later by the programmer can be seperated.

So check build-impl.xml then.

It contains the following sections:

> - initialization
> - compilation
> - jar
> - execution
> - debugging
> - javadoc
> - junit compilation
> - junit execution
> - junit debugging
> - applet
> - cleanup

In the initialization part, the targets inits many things for the build, including many macrodefs. You may see things like `<j2seproject1:java classname="${run.class}"/>`, they are not netbeans-only tasks. They are actually macros defined in the initialization section of the build file.

So, actually, you can run the build without netbeans installed. However, to use it in eclipse, you may need to do a cleanup and some modifications. You may need to check all the properties defined in `nbproject/project.properties`; you may need to delete other netbeans project files that will never be used after converted to eclipse project.

Or, maybe, just creating an eclipse project from existing source could be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation here.  I agree that Eclipse seems to work with the build-impl.xml file pretty well.  Well enough in fact that I found in my recent case, only had to apply certain classpath changes to the project.properties file in order to get everything to work.  One area of hangup was with the junit.jar reference from ant.  If Eclipse is unable to find this jar reference with its internal Ant, then just add the pathname to that jar file in your test classpath property, which is probably in your project.properties file.